# Помогите написать программу, которая будет определять , является ли цифрой , введенный объект?

Tags: c++

1. Считать символ и определить, является ли он цифрой.

Comment: И в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isdigit

Answer (score 4):

Вот функция:

```
bool isDigit(const char ch) {
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}
```